# How do I pick values from an array without having repeating values in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

- I am using `C#` and I have an array that stores 20 `integers`.
- I have 3 variables and I would like to assign them all to randomly-picked integers from the `array`, but I have to make it so that the values picked from the `array` are not the same.
- Is there any way to do this other than by using a lot of `if statements`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: search for "shuffle"

Comment: Sure; use two if statements! Its really not *that* hard. If you use an array instead of three variables, you can use a loop and get it down to one `if`.

Comment: I think randomly shuffling an array will require slightly a lot of code. But if the array have been shuffled already, then you can take 3 distinct value from the array easily through LINQ, e.g. "shuffledArray.Distinct().Take(3).ToArray()"

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Check out my answer.  I implemented your suggestion into a pretty simple design.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on ThariqNugrohotomo's suggestion regarding selecting three distinct values from a shuffled array.  I implemented a version of [Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is based on [DotNetPerls example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle).  The reason three distinct values are selected after the shuffle is performed is due to the fact that the source array may have repeating values.  If we simply shuffle them, then there's a possibility of duplicates.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ShuffleAndTakeUnique
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Random _random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 11, 12, 20, 19, 18, 17, 15, 16, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14 };
            var values = Shuffle<int>(array).Distinct().Take(3).ToArray();

            foreach(var val in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }

        public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] source)
        {
            T[] array = new T[source.Length];
            Array.Copy(source, array, source.Length);
            var random = _random;

            for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
            {
                int j = random.Next(i);
                T tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = tmp;
            }

            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

**Below are older ideas:**

Here's a quick and dirty `Console Application` that stores three unique `int` values in a `List<int>`.  You may then assign the values from that list to your variables.  The list serves as a way to ensure uniqueness of the values.  This is just an example, so obviously alter it to your needs and clean it up.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();
        static int[] array = { 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 11, 12, 20, 19, 18, 17, 15, 16, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14 };
        static List<int> results = new List<int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (results.Count < 3)
            {
                int num = array[random.Next(array.Length)];
                if (!results.Contains(num))
                {
                    results.Add(num);
                }
            }

            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's an example that uses a generic method that will give you back an array of specified length (up to the maximum of the original array) that contains unique values from the original array:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GetUniqueValues
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array1 = { 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 11, 12, 20, 19, 18, 17, 15, 16, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14 };
            var values1 = GetUniqueValues<int>(array1, 3);

            foreach (var val in values1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }

            string[] array2 = { "apple", "orange", "cherry", "melon", "grapefruit", "grapes", "peach", "watermelon" };
            var values2 = GetUniqueValues<string>(array2, 4);

            foreach (var val in values2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }

        public static T[] GetUniqueValues<T>(T[] array, int valuesCount)
        {
            var values = new List<T>();

            if (array != null && array.Length > 0 && valuesCount > 0)
            {                   
                var distinctCount = array.Distinct().Count();
                if (valuesCount > distinctCount)
                {
                    valuesCount = distinctCount;
                }

                var random = new Random();

                while(values.Count < valuesCount)
                {
                    T val = array[random.Next(array.Length)];
                    if (!values.Contains(val))
                    {
                        values.Add(val);
                    }
                }
            }

            return values.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I make sure that the number of distinct values in the array is not less than the requested number of values.  Otherwise, we'd be stuck in an infinite loop.  If you pass an empty array or a count less than one, it will return an empty array.  I prefer that over `null`... but once again, it's up to you.

Another way is to pass a copy of the original array as a `List<T>` and remove any occurrence of a value, once it's picked.  That way, there is no way you can ever choose it again.  Here's a quick, untested draft (I didn't test this at all), but you'll get the idea:

```
while(values.Count < valuesCount && list.Count > 0)
{
    T val = list[random.Next(list.Count)];
    values.Add(val);
    list.RemoveAll(val);
}
```